# In Django, what does latest('date') return when there's more than one possible result?

Tags: django

I'm in the very beginning stages of understanding Django and have started work on a project to help me learn it. In writing some models, I've come to a situation where I want to use latest() but there could be more than one object with the same "latest" date.

In the Django documentation for [latest](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#latest), it says

> Like get(), latest() raises DoesNotExist if there is no object with the given parameters.

But, what does latest() do if there's more than one object with the same "latest" date? I suspect it raises [MultipleObjectsReturned](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/exceptions/#django.core.exceptions.MultipleObjectsReturned) as get() would do, but since this isn't stated in the documentation, I'm asking here. I actually hope that it returns the latest object created, i.e., the one with the largest primary key. If it doesn't do that, what would be the correct get() statement that would get the latest by date and if there's more than one, then the greatest by primary key?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [`QuerySet.latest()` method source code](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/db/models/query.py#L481), it is not the case - `latest()` does not raise `MultipleObjectsReturned`, because it limits the result to 1 element:

```py
def latest(self, field_name=None):
    """
    Returns the latest object, according to the model's 'get_latest_by'
    option or optional given field_name.
    """
    latest_by = field_name or self.model._meta.get_latest_by
    assert bool(latest_by), "latest() requires either a field_name parameter or 'get_latest_by' in the model"
    assert self.query.can_filter(), \
        "Cannot change a query once a slice has been taken."
    obj = self._clone()
    obj.query.set_limits(high=1)  # <-- see here
    obj.query.clear_ordering()
    obj.query.add_ordering('-%s' % latest_by)
    return obj.get()
```

`get()` however, [as visible in its source code](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/db/models/query.py#L366), raises `MultipleObjectsReturned` only if the number of results is different than `1` (when it actually returns this result) and different than `0` (when it raises `DoesNotExist`).

So although `latest()` returns result of `get()`, the `get()` works on something that has no more than 1 element and you do not need to worry about that corner case. Hopefully it is clear enough.

I believe in this case (when two or more records have the same latest date) Django relies on what is returned from the database.

Comment: Thanks. Looks like latest() does what I want it to do. In my question I said I wanted the greatest primary key, but in reality, it doesn't matter. As long as there's no exception thrown and there's a single object returned, it'll work for me.

Comment: @ColinKeenan: I missed that, but if you will want to take the approach of returning the element with biggest primary key, you could do that - just supply its name as argument to `latest()`, or omit it and set model's `Meta` inner class property `get_latest_by` to the string containing the name of the primary key. The first approach would look like this: `SomeModel.objects.latest('id')` for most common case.

Comment: Thanks again in case I need that. For now, I really wanted the date. I was thinking that behind the scenes, it might choose between more than one on the same date by looking at the primary key.